# Why does Object.toString throws SyntaxError while Array.slice doesn't?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax-error, prototype

Why is it that typing this in the console:

```
{}.toString
{}.hasOwnProperty
{}....
```

throws an SyntaxError, and typing:

```
[].slice
[].filter
({}).toString
({}.toString)
```

doesn't?

What is the difference between the Array and the Object?

Comment: What do you expect `{}....` to do?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I ment `{}.`... eg. `{}.isPrototypeOf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the ambiguity of the `{` symbol.  Try this:

```
({}.toString())
```

When the parser sees `{}` at the very beginning of a new statement, it has to choose between

- Is this an object literal?
- Is this a statement block?

It always chooses the second one, a statement block.  Thus `{}` is an empty statement block, and `.toString()` right after that makes no sense.

There's no ambiguity with `[]` — an `[` at the beginning of a statement can only be the start of an array literal (as part of an expression statement).  However there are similar problems with the `function` keyword, which does double-duty as the start of a function declaration statement and the start of a function instantiation expression.

Comment: `({}).toString()` will do also.

Comment: @elclanrs I don't think that can possibly be true. Firefox 17 throws a syntax error.  It's a basic characteristic of the grammar.

Comment: Chrome v23 also throws a syntax error.  Its not a browser issue, just a result of the spec.

Comment: @Pointy, take the following code. It even works on IE8. http://jsbin.com/eqihos/1/edit. But I've seen browsers having problems without parenthesis thus `({})` will work fine.

Comment: @elclanrs, the console acts a bit differently (eval scope, I think).

Comment: @GCC: Yeah I think that's the case because I've used `{}` in many projects and it works fine as a raw expression in most modern browsers. It must be the `return` in that case that says "this is an object literal"

Comment: @elclanrs yes definitely - the ambiguity only comes up when `{` is the first character of a new statement. If you've already started a `return` statement, then the only thing that  `{` can be is the start of an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

Because <strike>in the console</strike> `{}` is treated as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), and not an object.  To make it think it's an object use `({})`:

```
({}).toString
```

Comment: Not only in the console, in other environments as well.

Comment: @FelixKling: True, this is the case in most places.